# How to create an array given a line of input with integers where the first integer is the length?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create a function that returns the address of an array which is created by taking a single line of input from the user where the first integer is the length. For example if the input from the user was "5 19 8 26 12 9" the corresponding array would be [19, 8, 26, 12, 9] (Which is of length 5).

The way I went about doing this was rather than taking input from the user while after the function ran I took it as arguments (argc,argv) Ex. "./a.out 5 19 8 26 12 9". I was wondering if there were any other possible solutions that exist perhaps using scanf or cin...

Comment: If you want to use `cin` but avoid needing a sentinel, just have the user enter all the numbers in one line, extract the whole line with `std::getline()` and then parse out the ints with `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @CruzJean That's no different from parsing out the integers with `cin` from the get-go.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It avoids having to check for new line characters manually to stop extracting values. The alternatives are prefixing the sequence with a length or having a terminating sentry.

Comment: @CruzJean The OP didn't say there were multiple lines of input though. And if you already know the format, you don't need a sentinel.

Comment: @CruzJean The number of integers are given to us so we know when to stop.

Comment: @CruzJean What you gave was a valid solution. I was just pointing out how it was needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general question of how to designate the extent of a sequence of data items which has dynamic length.

Interestingly, there aren't actually many programming patterns to go about this (though there are many ways to implement them). The problem effectively boils down to a simple question: how do I know when to stop taking values?

When you receive values that are already stored (e.g. argc/argv or passing in an array or some other container), you already have the values and you know how many there are. This is the trivial case. Parsing data from a file or from the terminal is where things start to get interesting.

Here's a list of frequently-used "stopping mechanisms" (with all others to my knowledge being specific applications of prefix and/or suffix).

### Prefixed Sequence

This is the method you described. In its most general sense it involves prefixing the input with something that tells you how much data is there. This could be human-level as the number of elements following it, or machine-level as e.g. the number of bytes to receive from a network connection.

Here's an example that uses the number of elements in an input sequence as a prefix.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
int count, temp;

std::cin >> count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> temp;
    vec.push_back(temp);
}
```

Note that using this method you immediately know the total number of elements in the sequence, which you can use to simplify the code and reduce the number of dynamic allocations:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
int count;

std::cin >> count;
vec.resize(count); // performs only one allocation
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) std::cin >> vec[i];
```

Example user input (console or file):

```
4 3 5
4 88 -90
2
```

Resulting values (vec):

```
3, 5, 4, 88
```

### Suffixed Sequence

Similar to the prefix sequence, you can also suffix the sequence with some value that denotes where to stop. This is typically referred to as a terminator (e.g. C-style strings are terminated by a a zero byte i.e. `'\0'`).

This example shows how to read a sequence of non-negative integers. We use the first negative value as the stopping condition:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
int temp;

while (std::cin >> temp && temp >= 0) vec.push_back(temp);
```

Example user input (console or file):

```
4 3 5
4 88 -90
2
```

Resulting values (vec):

```
4, 3, 5, 4, 88
```

### Reaching EOF

EOF (end of file) can be used as a stopping mechanism if you're reading from a file. It's essentially a system-specific combination of prefix and/or suffix. For instance, the specific filesystem structure being used will typically store the length of the file in bytes. This is essentially the prefix method (although the prefix value doesn't actually appear in the data sequence in this case).

This method is popular because it's very common to have a file that contains only a sequence of same-type elements. It can be used with `cin`, but only if `cin` has been redirected from a file (as otherwise you'd never - traditionally - reach the end since it'll just interactively wait for more input as a console session).

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::ifstream file("nums.txt");
int temp;

while (file >> temp) vec.push_back(temp);
```

In fact this use is so common that the STL added `std::istream_iterator` for making this easy to write in a safe, library-ish way. In this case it's not really better, but depending on what you're doing iterators can be more convenient - e.g. you could feed them into `std::accumulate()` to get the sum. Here's an example of using `std::istream_iterator` to do the same thing:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::ifstream file("nums.txt");

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(file), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
    std::back_inserter(vec));
```

Example user input (file):

```
4 3 5
4 88 -90
2
```

Resulting values (vec):

```
4, 3, 5, 4, 88, -90, 2
```

### End of Line

Using the end of line (i.e. `'\n'`) as a stopping condition is technically a suffixed sequence method, but it's different enough and common enough that I feel it should be addressed directly, especially in regards to what you're trying to accomplish.

You could use the unformatted input functions line `std::cin.get()` to manually search for the characters you want to keep or ignore, but this is tedious and error-prone. The method I'll be demonstrating is slower than the manual method, but if performance is not a concern they are vastly superior (especially for more complex types with overloaded stream extraction operators).

We'll read an entire line of text from `cin` (which is terminated by new line character `'\n'`), and then parse out its values after the fact.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::string line;
int temp;

std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream ss(line);
while (ss >> temp) vec.push_back(temp);
```

And if you want to use standard utilities (or if you need iterators):

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::string line;

std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream ss(line);
std::copy(std::istream_itereator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
    std::back_inserter(vec));
```

Example user input (console or file):

```
4 3 5
4 88 -90
2
```

Resulting values (vec):

```
4, 3, 5
```

Comment: Very thorough answer and very well formatted. Only additional points that could be touched on are `std::cin.clear()` and `std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` in the event of an invalid input is encountered, etc.. but that does not detract from your answer.